# how to find the IPv4 Address of a program running if you are using 2 network adapter

Tags: ip, ipv4

i am using 2 diffrent network adapter, every one got 2 ip IPv4 Address how to find the IPv4 Address of a program running in win 10 not the local ip or the target , i mean the public ip , because i have 4 ip in 2 network adabpter or i want to focus 1 ip for 1 program like chrome or firefox Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Your public IP is the one assigned to your router, not any assigned to your network adaptors. Google "What's my IP address?"

Comment: i use 2 router in one pc , is there any way to know the IP address that open in the .exe ( like firefox or any program ) because i want every .exe with different ip , i hope you understand me , thx